# .desktop file to pass arguments received to Exec

Tags: command-line, .desktop

I have a desktop file with this contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Mozilla Firefox - default
Type=Application
Comment=Web Application
Exec=/usr/lib/firefox/firefox
Icon=/home/noit/Desktop/ff-channel-base-iconsets/dev/dev512.png
```

I launch this desktop file with various arguments from terminal and from c function `g_app_info_launch_uris` docs seen [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GAppInfo.html#g-app-info-launch-uris):

How can I make the arguments that passed to the desktop file be passed to the Exec?

Comment: Why exec a .desktop file, not run the exec?

Comment: I run multiple profiles in Firefox and to give each profile a unique icon I have to use a .desktop file. As the app takes the icon of the .desktop file. Otherwise I havea bunch of Firefox icons and cant tell which is what profile :(

Comment: You do  have some options, but you cannot run a .desktop file itself with arguments.

Comment: Ah ok thanks @JacobVlijm ill just make the script edit the exec line before launching it. and then edit back to what it was after launch :(

Comment: Actually an interesting thought!

Comment: @Noitidart when you finish that, please post as an answer!